# set (homescreen) widget size programmatically (from configuration utility)

Tags: android, widget, size

Is it possible to set the widget dimensions different from values set in *appwidget-provider* xml?

The point is to configure the size with configuration activity so one can choose 1x1 or 3x1 style widget.

Thanks.